# How can I find out what flags I compiled nginx with?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to find out what flags I compiled nginx with so that I can recompile it but every time I type nginx -V or -v it's giving me nginx 0.91 or something like that.

Can anybody offer some insight?

Answer (score 3):

On an Ubuntu machine -V works as expected for me:

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.1.19
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl --with-md5=/usr/include/openssl --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module
```

The -V option was added in nginx 0.5.5 so it should be available to you. Could it have been compiled without any options? What is the exact and complete output of `nginx -V`?